# SELECT query not accepting these characters !@#$%^&*()_+

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm testing for bugs and figure this out:

I have this sample unique value " qwe !@#$%^&*()_+ " (w/o quotes) to be `$_REQUEST` to other page to display using Select query.

I tried `mysql_escape_string` and `mysql_real_escape_string` but it's not working.

Comment: check this: url_encode('url');

Comment: Please show how your query is constructed and executed.

Comment: @devpro thank you! you're really a pro!

Comment: now i am convert it into answer, than you can accept the answer, it will help to others..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) here as i suggested you in comments:

```
$yourURL = "url with special characters...";
$yourURL = urlencode($yourURL); // encoded url
```